# Failed to run Maven clean install in azure DevOps

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, artifactory

I am trying to do maven clean install in azure DevOps and publish the artifacts into jfrog.
However my project is having dependencies. If I run locally by adding jfrog credentials in settings.xml its working, when I try this in azure devops pipeline its failing as it failing to download the dependencies from jfrog.

Here is my YAML Code

```
trigger:
- master


pool:
 vmImage: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- task: Maven@3
 inputs:
   mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
   goals: 'clean deploy'
   publishJUnitResults: true
   testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
   javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
   mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
   mavenAuthenticateFeed: true
   effectivePomSkip: false



- task: JFrogPublishBuildInfo@1
 inputs:
   artifactoryConnection: 'Token-'
   buildName: '$(Build.DefinitionName)'
   buildNumber: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

This is my pipeline error
[image]

what should i do in-order to achieve this. How can I download the dependencies from jfrog artifactory during my build and publish back to jfrog.

Comment: After some tweaking, fixed the issue using suggested approach, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you have defined the Jfrog credentials in the `settings.xml`. And it can work on your local machine.

In Azure DevOps, you can upload the settings.xml to repo and specify the settings.xml file in the maven task.

For example: `options: '-s settings.xml'`

```
trigger:
- master


pool:
 vmImage: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- task: Maven@3
 inputs:
   mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
   goals: 'clean deploy'
   options: '-s filepath/settings.xml'
   publishJUnitResults: true
   testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
   javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
   mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
   mavenAuthenticateFeed: true
   effectivePomSkip: false


- task: JFrogPublishBuildInfo@1
 inputs:
   artifactoryConnection: 'Token-'
   buildName: '$(Build.DefinitionName)'
   buildNumber: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [JFrog Maven task](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-azure-devops-extension?tab=readme-ov-file#jfrog-maven-task) from the extension [JFrog](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JFrog.jfrog-azure-devops-extension) instead of the `Maven@3` task.

> The JFrog Maven task allows triggering Maven builds, while **resolving dependencies** and deploying artifacts from and to Artifactory. The task uses the configured JFrog Artifactory V2 service connection. The task can also be configured to capture build-info and store the downloaded and uploaded artifacts as build dependencies and build artifacts. The captured build-info can be later published to Artifactory using the JFrog Publish Build-Info task.

[image]